# Can i prevent win7 from creating that kind of file ending with "~"?

Tags: windows-7

In my working directory,there are many files ending with "~"?
can i prevent win7 from creating that kind of file?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form the screenshot you provided, I'm sure files with suffix `~` is produced by `gvim`.

Vim uses ~ file to make a backup of the file which you edited.

You may refer to [Why does Vim save files with a ~ extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607435/why-does-vim-save-files-with-a-extension) for more details and instructions on how to avoid that.

Comment: I think Emacs creates them also. Though I suppose you're more likely to end up with Vim "inadvertently" on Windows than Emacs. It might be included in Git for windows.

Comment: @BradyTrainor Yes, you are right. Emacs and many other programs also create a ~ file when modifing an existing file. For this particular question, I come to my conclusion from the screenshot provided. You may see the icon of vim before the filename.

Answer (score 9):

Windows is *not* responsible for creating that file. And it is also not responsible for preventing creation of files with legal names.

Appending a `~` to the file name/extension is a common way for many programs to create a backup copy of the original file before saving, just in case you want to undo your changes. This is actually a more common pattern on FOSS/Linux programs, and tends to be carried with them when they are ported to Windows. Deal with whichever editor is creating the files in the first place.

Comment: Not Correct not only Foss/Linux Tools like gvim does it also word/Excel/Powerpoint make such files but thy have a different meaning they stand for the Actual open Document and are automatically removed when the file is closed.

Comment: @konqui I meant the `~` to denote temporary files is a common pattern across FOSS programs. That *does not* mean other programs can't use it, and it *also* does not mean the pattern cannot mean anything else. MS Office doesn't use tildes anyway; its temporary file naming scheme is different. At no point did I say other programs may not create temporary files.